# Function vs if-statement: Function is not working, but the code in the function will work when outside a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I was working on building a randomized character generator for Pathfinder 3.5 and got stuck.

I am using the Populate_Skills(Skill_String, Draw, Skill_List, Class_Skill): function to populate a randiomized list of skills with their class based points total, class bonus, and point buy. So modelling the action of a player picking skills for their character.

As an example below, Wizards.

I pick Knowledge_Arcana as a skill and spend one of my skill point pool (Calculated by taking my intelligence modifier +2) on it. So that skill now equals my intelligence modifier(+1 in this case), class skill bonus as a wizard (+3), plus the point I spent(+1) for a total of 5.

The problem is while the function prints the correct result of 5, the outstanding variables do not populate with the final total. To continue our example I'd run the function on Knowledge_Arcana, get a +5, and then check the Knowledge_Arcana after the function call and get just +1. Conversely, if I write out the function as just an if statement it works. Example is next to the function for comparison.

Does anyone know why Im getting the different result?

```
## Creating the lists and breaking into two separate sections

Int_Mod = 1
Skill_Ranks = 3
Rand_Class = 'Wizard'
Knowledge_Arcana = Int_Mod
Knowledge_Dungeoneering = Int_Mod
Wizard_Class_Top_Skills = ["Knowledge_Arcana"]
Wizard_Class_Less_Skills = ["Knowledge_Dungeoneering"]
Class_Skill = 3
Important_Skills_Weighted = .6
Less_Important_Skills_Weighted = .4
Important_Skills_Total_Weighted = round(Skill_Ranks*Important_Skills_Weighted)
Less_Skill_Total_Weighted = round(Skill_Ranks*Less_Important_Skills_Weighted)
Wiz_Draw =['Knowledge_Arcana', 'Knowledge_Dungeoneering']


def Populate_Skills(Skill_String, Draw, Skill_List, Class_Skill):
    if Skill_String in Draw:
        Skill_List = Skill_List + Class_Skill + Draw.count(Skill_String)
        print(Skill_String, Skill_List)
    else:
        print('Nuts!')



## Function Calls

Populate_Skills('Knowledge_Arcana', Wiz_Draw, Knowledge_Arcana, Class_Skill)
Populate_Skills('Knowledge_Dungeoneering', Wiz_Draw, Knowledge_Dungeoneering, Class_Skill)

print(Knowledge_Arcana,Knowledge_Dungeoneering)
```

Edited to be a MRE, I believe. Sorry folks, Im new.

Comment: Please reduce to a [mre].

Comment: On how to do that: if you can cause the bug you want our help with only one variable, simplify the code to have only one variable. A good mre is short enough to let folks focus squarely on the problem itself with no distractions.

Comment: That said, if I had to guess (and I do), I'd hazard that when you put this code into a function you're still expecting it to modify global variables when doing assignments. That guess should give you enough keywords to be able to search up a relevant duplicate already in our knowledge base.

Comment: Charles I did some checking and you are right. I do want to modify the global variable from in the function, but also I need it as a parameter and from a cursory Google Search (and python throwing an error) that doesnt seem to work. Like in the example above the Global variable being updated needs to be Knowledge_Arcana or Knowledge_Dungeoneering, but they are also currently required as parameter inputs. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This is hardly minimal. If your problem is really accessing a global variable from a function, a minimal example would have one variable and one function, and no Pandas etc.

Comment: triplee I was leaving it in as a consolidated piece of code because the current theory is global versus local. I will reduce it more happily, just looking for potential work arounds of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a reference to a list and expect the function to modify it; but you are reassigning the variable inside the function which creates a local variable, which is then lost when the function is exited.  You want to manipulate the same variable which the caller passed in, instead.

```py
def Populate_Skills(Skill_String, Draw, Skill_List, Class_Skill):
    if Skill_String in Draw:
        Skill_List.extend(Class_Skill + Draw.count(Skill_String))
        print(Skill_String, Skill_List)
    else:
        print('Nuts!')
```

Alternatively, have the function return the new value, and mandate for the caller to pick it up and assign it to the variable.

```py
def Populate_Skills(Skill_String, Draw, Skill_List, Class_Skill):
    if Skill_String in Draw:
        Skill_List = Skill_List + Class_Skill + Draw.count(Skill_String)
        print(Skill_String, Skill_List)
    else:
        print('Nuts!')
    return Skill_List

Skill_List = Populate_Skills('Knowledge_Arcana', Wiz_Draw, Knowledge_Arcana, Class_Skill)
# etc
```

You should *probably* also rename your variables (capital letters should be used for classes and globals; regular Python functions and variables should use `snake_case`) and avoid using global variables at all. The entire program looks like you should probably look into refactoring it into objects, but that's far beyond the scope of what you are asking.

Comment: The issue was the lack of return. Thank you for clarifying the return statement and recording the variable globally, that was super informative!

Comment: No, the real issue in your original code is described in the first sentence.